# Repeating an item on the third Wednesday of every second month

Tags: elisp, org-mode

I'm trying to make an org-mode entry repeat on the third Wednesday of every second month.

So far, I have succeeded in creating an entry that repeats every Wednesday of every second month:

```
SCHEDULED: <%%(and (= 3 (calendar-day-of-week date)) (oddp (car date)))%>
```

Is there a function I'm missing (doesn't seem to be anything in `calendar.el`) that will tell me which Wednesday the date is?

Comment: Try looking at sexp entries for dates and calendars. The manual page suggests this is doable: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Sexp-Diary-Entries.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @brittUWaterloo for the suggestion; you're right, and the correct solution is:

```
SCHEDULED: <%%(and (diary-float t 3 3) (oddp (car date)))%>
```